# Spring JMS + JTA DMLC and Message Groups

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

My application requires that all messages with a particular group id be processed by the same thread.  I tried to set this up using the DMLC, but as I am seeing messages being processed, they are being handled by separate threads within DMLC when concurrency is set > 1.  My hope was that I could have multiple consumers reading from the queue each with different message groups, but I am not seeing the desired behavior with this setup.  Is there a way using DMLC or SMLC (with JTA) to support multiple listeners on a queue where all messages with a particular group id are handled by the same thread, without setting the concurrency to 1?  I'm nearing the point where I believe SMLC and DMLC will not meet this need and I will need to use a different implementation to handle this case.  Are there any examples or advice on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code that exhibits this behavior? I just ran a test while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105929/spring-jms-concurrency-and-jmsxgroupid/39107120#39107120) and it works perfectly fine for me with all messages for the same group going to the same thread.

Comment: yes, will post shortly, if it matters I'm also running Spring 3.2.11

Comment: that question was actually asked by a co-worker.  I don't think having this question open will make sense so I will delete shortly so we can focus on a single issue.

Comment: I am testing with Spring 4.3 but I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: I just tested with Spring 3.2.11 and it still works for me.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I will try again.  Any chance you have this application available where I could test locally?

Comment: I modified the [Spring Integration JMS Sample App](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/80f49396875336b2acb0668401536e9755bdb4f3) to add the header and enabled debug logging for `o.s.jms` so I can see which thread the message is delivered on. When dropping back to Spring 3.2.11 (and Spring Integration 3.0.7) needs a bit more refactoring in Main because of some package changes.